# Problem in getting Contact Info

Tags: android, sms

I m working on application in which i have to send all contacts from Android mobile to other   mobile through SMS. I don't have any problem in getting contact information but when I send those Contacts after few messages there is Alert Window pop up saying "A large number of message have being send" and ask if you want to send or not.
I am testing this application on HTC Hero.
Is this problem is for specific mobiles or for all?
I don't know what should i do to avoid this window because I cant get SMS Sent event.
Please help me with any ideas that i can implement........

Comment: Sounds like a rather inefficient way of sending contacts...maybe you should rethink your approach. If you still need this functionality, then add some throttling so that it doesn't send so many messages so quickly, but rather on scheduled intervals/batches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The alert window doesn't appear after a "few messages" — the limit is 100 messages, per application, per hour, before that warning appears.

If you really must use SMS, then I would suggest bundling multiple contacts together or batching the sends over time — short of rooting the phone, there is no way to get around this (sensible and useful) warning.

See also: http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/587f0d3a03ced88a

Answer (score 1):

I think this a security check back to inform the user that an app is wasting a lot of money through sending a lot of SMS messages. If the use case of your app is valid you have to convince the user that sending all this messages is necessary and that he has to click the send button.

I hope and thinkg that there is no way to program around this because this a very sensible thing to do for a phone.